# OpenPyXL error by saving of workbook: DefinedName with the same name and scope already exists

Tags: python, excel, xlsx, openpyxl

I want edit one cell in a Excel-XLSX file with OpenPyXL in Python and then save this changed file into a xlsx with other name. 
But i get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 File "E:\ExcelPythonTest\workspace\ExcelTest\ExcelTest.py", line 14, in <module>
    book.save(path2)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.4.0b1-py2.7.egg\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 294, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.4.0b1-py2.7.egg\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 270, in save_workbook
    writer.save(filename)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.4.0b1-py2.7.egg\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 251, in save
    self.write_data()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.4.0b1-py2.7.egg\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 94, in write_data
    archive.writestr(ARC_WORKBOOK, write_workbook(self.workbook))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.4.0b1-py2.7.egg\openpyxl\writer\workbook.py", line 121, in write_workbook
    defined_names.append(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.4.0b1-py2.7.egg\openpyxl\workbook\defined_name.py", line 191, in append
    raise ValueError("""DefinedName with the same name and scope already exists""")
ValueError: DefinedName with the same name and scope already exists
```

My Code:

```
import os
import openpyxl

# Change this to suit
path = r'E:\ExcelPythonTest\example.xlsx'
path2 = r'E:\ExcelPythonTest\examle_UHAHAHAHAHHA.xlsx'

book = openpyxl.load_workbook( path )
sheet = book.get_sheet_by_name('Dictionary')
print sheet['G8'].value
sheet['G8'] =  3.18
print sheet['G8'].value

book.save(path2)
```

Can anyone help me?

P.S: i have tried to edit the same .xlsx with code in C and c-library libxl . So i think the xlsx file doen't have problem.

I have tried the following code without any editing of xlsx:

```
import os
import openpyxl

# Change this to suit
path = r'E:\ExcelPythonTest\Dt_RECORD_SHPS_RM_ROStruct.xlsx'
path2 = r'E:\ExcelPythonTest\Dt_RECORD_SHPS_RM_ROStruct_UHAHAHAHAHHA.xlsx'

book = openpyxl.load_workbook( path )

book.save(path2)
```

But the same error was occurred.

Comment: Your code works for me. Can you post the XLSX file please?

Comment: I can't post my xlsx file here. sorry. because this is a parameter from my company.

Comment: If you try to save into the same file, what happens? And what prints  `sheet['G8']` and `sheet['G8'].number_format`?

Comment: You should submit a bug on the openpyxl bug tracker but without a file we can't really help you very much. The file can be sent by e-mail if you're worried about confidential information. But you might also want to try a checkout of the 2.4 branch which contains some improvements on the handling of defined names.

Comment: For information, I used the same version (2.4.0b1) and no error for me. But I am on Debian, not Windows.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should be submitted as a bug to the library (I'm the maintainer). Without the source file  the error is not reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I battled with the same problem at work until figuring out the solution. You only need to add one line to your existing code. I don't exactly know what the definedName objects are good for but the resulting file is not broken (unlike without the line) and doesn't seem to have any visual differences caused by clearing the definedNames list.

```
import os
import openpyxl

# Change this to suit
path = r'E:\ExcelPythonTest\example.xlsx'
path2 = r'E:\ExcelPythonTest\examle_UHAHAHAHAHHA.xlsx'

book = openpyxl.load_workbook( path )
sheet = book.get_sheet_by_name('Dictionary')
print sheet['G8'].value
sheet['G8'] =  3.18
print sheet['G8'].value

# This fixes it   
book.defined_names.definedName = []

book.save(path2)
```